# Modify the URL with the variable

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to add a variable to the URL as
www.example.com/index.cgi?username=demo

I have a form in index.html which has action=login.cgi

In login.cgi

```
if (($cgi->param('username') eq 'demo') && ($cgi->param('password') eq 'demo')) {
my cookie= CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'username', -value=>$cgi->param('username'));
print $cgi->redirect(-uri => 'index.cgi', -cookie => $cookie);
}
else {
print $cgi->redirect(-uri => 'index.html');
}
```

In index.cgi

```
my $username = $cookies{username}->value;
```

So I want to modify the URL for index.cgi such that it adds the username on it as well from the variable $username

```
www.example.com/index.cgi?username=demo
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: how to modify the URL? Once the value of the form is passed in index.html and if the username is demo the url of index.cgi be as index.cgi?usename=demo

Comment: Are you asking how to append to a string? Try the [dot operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators)

Comment: I am asking how to append the URL with variable something like _GET["username"]

Comment: OK, have you tried using the `.` operator?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine strings using the dot operator or double quotes.

Using the dot operator: `my $url = 'www.example.com/index.cgi?username=' . $username;`.

Using double quotes: `my $url = "www.example.com/index.cgi?username=$username";`.

You can combine multiple strings:

```
my $base_url = 'www.example.com/index.cgi';
my $key = 'username';
my $value = $username;
my $url = "$base_url?$key=$value";
```

Do not forget to escape special characters (such as & or %) in your strings:

```
use URI::Escape;
$username = uri_escape $username;
```

If you have a hash of keys and values, you can use this:

```
use URI::Escape;
my %h = (username => 'demo', password => 'demo', topic => 'perl');
my $url = 'www.example.com/index.cgi';
$url .= '?' . join '&', map {uri_escape "$_=$h{$_}"} keys %h;
```